# Pygame gfxdraw program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am a beginner with pygame. I want to include a few "Emitter" classes to "Particle" class to show points. It doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it. I think the problem is with gfxdraw. In the "Emitter" class, it initializes the system window. This can also be a problem. I don't know how to transfer this to the "Particle" class. Would it help at all? I used many combinations for repair. Nothing works. Please help. Does anyone have any idea?

```
import random
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.gfxdraw

class ParticleSystem:
    def __init__(self, id, pos, a,b, width, height, radius, color):
        self.id = id
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.g = 9.81
        self.pos = [random.randint(a,b), 0]
        self.enabled = True
        self.df = 0

    def update(self, time, collision):
        if self.enabled:
            v = 1 / float(time)
            if not self.collision_detect(collision):
                self.pos[1] += self.g*v
            else:
                self.enabled = False
            if self.df != 0:
                F = (self.g*v)/9
                if self.df < 0:
                    F = -F                
                self.pos[0] += F
                self.df -= F

    def collision_detect(self, collision):        
        x = int(self.pos[0])
        y = self.pos[1]
        r = self.radius
        points = collision[x-r:x+r]        
        for p in points:
            if y + r >= p:
                for i in range(x-r, x+r):
                    if i >= 0 and i < self.width:
                        collision[i] = y
                return True

        if self.pos[1] >= self.height:
            return True                 
        else:
            return False

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, int(self.pos[0]), int(self.pos[1]), self.radius, self.color)        
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, int(self.pos[0]), int(self.pos[1]), self.radius, self.color)


class Emitter:
    def __init__(self, a, b, height, width):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.timer = 60
        self.width = width
        self.height = height       
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.background_color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.particles = []
        self.counter = 0
        self.freq = 5
        self.size = 4
        self.collision = [height] * width 
        self.df_c = 1
        self.df_f = 100
        self.begin()

    def begin(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        while 1:
            time = self.clock.get_time()
            self.update(time)
            self.clock.tick(self.timer)
            self.render(time)

    def update(self, time):      
        if self.counter > self.freq:
            self.counter = 0
            particle = ParticleSystem(len(self.particles), self.pos, self.a, self.b, self.width, self.height, self.size, self.color)
            self.particles.append(particle)
        else:
            self.counter += 1

        df_c = random.randint(0, 100)
        df_f = 0
        if df_c <= self.df_c:
            df_f = random.randint(-self.df_f, self.df_f)

        for part in self.particles:
            if part.enabled:
                if df_f != 0:
                    part.df = df_f
                part.update(time, self.collision)

    def render(self, time):
        surface = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size())
        surface.convert()
        surface.fill(self.background_color)

        for part in self.particles:
            part.draw(surface)

        self.screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()


class Particle:
    def __init__(self, width, height, caption):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.caption = caption
        self.initialization()

    def initialization(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.caption)

        #Emitter(0, self.width, self.height, self.width)
        Emitter(0, 125, self.height, self.width)
        Emitter(200, 500, self.height, self.width) #how to show the second Emitter 

        self.input(pygame.event.get())

    def input(self, events):
       for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               sys.exit(0)
           elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                   sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    particle = Particle(800, 600, "Particle System - Christmas Time")
```

Comment: There are a few inherent problems with your design. One being you have an infinite loop in your Emitter class that you never break out of. Because of this, your second instance of the Emitter class will never be created. Additionally, the input method in your Particle class is never reached as well.

On top of this, it's not really clear what you're asking for. A second pygame window?

Comment: @Axe319- I want to show several "Emitter" classes at the same time in one system window in my "Particle" class. How should I change this code?